# Как в форму письма в Wordpress передать значение переменной из формы (CF7)

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Есть поле которое добавляется в форму таким образом:

```
wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'mail_send', 'foobar_shortcode' );

    function foobar_shortcode() {
        $shord_code = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i'));
        return $shord_code;
}
```

И оно добавляется и все хорошо, но мне нужно чтобы это поле приходило также на почту, но оно не приходит
Вот таким образом я вставляю его в тело письма:
[mail_send]

Но вместо того чтобы приходило значение приходит просто надпись - [mail_send]

Как в тело письма передать это значение

Comment: Читай как делать правильно https://contactform7.com/2015/01/10/adding-a-custom-form-tag/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

думаю вот так будет лучше, потому что не понятно зачем просто отображать значение тега в форме...

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'add_form_tag_mail_send' );

function add_form_tag_mail_send() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'mail_send', 'mail_send_form_tag_handler' );
}
function mail_send_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
    return '<input type="hidden" name="mail_send" value="'.md5(date('Y-m-d H:i')).'">';
}
```

Comment: Просто при заходе на страницу формируется этот хэш

Comment: И при отправке он должен класться в тело письма
И я не могу просто передать его в тело письма не получается

Comment: Все получилось
Затупил